# SCCM query for OS version not returning expected results

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-10, sccm

I'm trying to set up some device collections to use for Windows 10 Servicing in SCCM (version 1906). I want to create a collection for each version of Windows 10 (E.g. 1511, 1607, ..., 1909). I wasn't sure where to start with the query so I did some searching and found this query on Microsoft TechNet (This example is for build 17134 I.e. 1803):

```
select SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client from SMS_R_System inner join SMS_G_System_OPERATING_SYSTEM on SMS_G_System_OPERATING_SYSTEM.ResourceId = SMS_R_System.ResourceId where SMS_G_System_OPERATING_SYSTEM.BuildNumber like "%17134%"
```

At first it appeared to be working, but then I noticed that the member counts are way out. You can see in this picture that there are 518 devices in the `Windows 10 Unknown Version` collection which just 'includes' the `All Windows 10` collection and 'excludes' all the other collections.

[image: Device Collections]

When I look at devices in the `Windows 10 Unknown Version` they are showing build numbers which should have been included in the queries I have set up. For example the picture below shows a number of devices with build `10.0.17134` which should have been included in the query for my `Windows 10 1803` collection (I have checked and they are not included). I'm expecting a figure closer to 500 with 1803 installed.

[image: Windows 10 Unknown Version Collection]

I have tried updating the membership of each group but that made no difference. I thought maybe a software inventory may be required, but SCCM clearly knows the build version of the devices so I don't know why some are being returned by the queries but not others.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI: there is a PowerShell script from MS that adds ~100 groups (including the groups you need), you can either cherry pick them or just use them all: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Set-of-Operational-SCCM-19fa8178

Comment: Thank you, the query in that script solved my problem.

Comment: OK great! You can answer your own question, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved using the following query which I took from the Microsoft scripts provided by Lenniey (https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Set-of-Operational-SCCM-19fa8178)

```
select SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client from SMS_R_System where SMS_R_System.Build = '10.0.17134'
```